# Preloading background images before html page loads completly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am making a new theme for my personal site with WordPress and Bootstrap. Everything is working fine except the preloading of images in the main page. I have 8 images in total, 4 on top and the other 4 show up on mouseover only. All images are background images in a column container. My problem is that the page loader is working well for the 4 top images but the other 4 don't load with loader, rather on mouseover.

How can I solve this? 
How can I have all 8 images preload before the page loads completely?

Here is the code for the loader:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;

    });
}
```

Here is the main CSS and HTML:
http://jsfiddle.net/qhmmnz1p/

and here is the main page 
http://eco-greece.com

Comment: You could just use the [blur filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) on hover rather than creating 4 additional assets.

Comment: You do not need any scripts to preload images.

Comment: it's not about the blur images, i just want to know if there is a way to preload all of 8 images ?

Comment: add the other images to `arrayOfImages`

Comment: You could also check [waitForImages plugin](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) and maybe combine with [CSS only image preloading](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/).

Comment: just visually hide the image in css and for hover display inline, why not?